# Intersection of curves on a surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have a question about Lemma 1.3 in Hartshorne (on page 358). He wants to prove that
$$\#(C\cap D)=\deg_C(L(D)\otimes \mathcal{O}_C).$$

Here, $L(D)$ is invertible sheaf on X correspond to a curve $D$ and $\deg_C$ is the degree of an invertible sheaf along $C$.

I want to know what does this degree mean? And what does $\mathcal{O}_C$ exactly mean?

Then, it is said that we have exact sequence 
$$
0 \to L(-D) \otimes \mathcal{O}_C \to \mathcal{O}_C \to \mathcal{O}_{C \cap D} \to 0.
$$
Why is this exact?

Comment: The sheaf $\mathcal{O}_C$ is the structure sheaf of $C$, so tensoring with $\mathcal{O}_C$ acts as restriction of an invertible sheaf on $X$ to one on $C$. The degree $\deg_C$ function is then just the usual degree of an invertible sheaf on a curve. Furthermore, the exact sequence comes from the ideal sheaf exact sequence for $D$: take $0 \to L(-D) \to \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}_D \to 0$, and then tensor with $\mathcal{O}_C$ to get the above exact sequence (recall that tensoring with an invertible sheaf is an exact functor).